# OAuth: Redirecting a user after the redirect_uri

Tags: oauth

Is it acceptable to redirect the client to another page after the client is redirected with the redirected URI? For example, say the client clicks the “Cancel” button and the authorization server redirects him/her to:

client.example.com/cb?error=access_denied&state=xyz

After that, I’d like my application to redirect the user to another page in my app. Is this allowed? I don’t see in RFC 6749 that I’m not allowed to do this which is why I’m asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not in the RFC because it's out of scope of OAuth2. The user redirects, got the appropriate query parameters, and now it's up to you again what you want the browser to do.

Comment: For the record there's an ongoing discussion in the OAuth 2.0 standards arena about whether returning an error with a redirect is good behavior since it may allow attackers (i.e. untrusted clients) to make 3rd-party domains/services display messages controlled by the attacker.